# Typescript type based on 3rd constructor parameter of generic

Tags: typescript, generics

How to get the type of constructor props of generic type? ... See example

```
type PatchableProps<T> = 
  T extends { [k: string | number]: any } 
  ? { [Key in keyof T]: PatchableProps<T[Key]> }
  : T | Patch

export class CompositionResource<Type extends ApiObject> {

  readonly identifier: string = "ICompositionResource";

  constructor(public readonly name: string, private readonly props: PatchableProps<ConstructorParameters<Type>[2]>) {
    
  }
}
export class Patch {
    constructor() {

    }
}

export class ApiObject {

    constructor(public readonly something1: string, public readonly something2: string, public readonly props: SomeOtherProps) {
    }
}

export interface SomeOtherProps {

}
```

What I want to get is I have a class that uses generics  ... I want to use the type of the PatchableProps => based on the type of the third constructor parameter of Type. This code brings the error I hope you understand what I want to do here.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please provide a self-contained [mre] where everything needed to reproduce is contained in this question as plaintext?  Ideally you'd remove any third-party or private types like `ApiObject` or `Patch.Patch` and replace them with native types, or, barring that, provide (minimal) definitions for them.   The idea is to have text others can just paste into their own IDEs and immediately get to work on the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Edited the example so it is minimal reproducible

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgao9m) what you're looking for?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `Type extends ApiObject`, the `ApiObject` type refers to *instances* of the `ApiObject` class, and not the *constructor*. If you want to extract constructor arguments, then you should change the constraint to a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures) that constructs `ApiObject` instances. Possibly like this:

```
export class CompositionResource<
  C extends new (arg0: any, arg1: any, arg2: any, ...args: any) => ApiObject
> {

  readonly identifier: string = "ICompositionResource";

  constructor(
    public readonly name: string,
    private readonly props: PatchableProps<ConstructorParameters<C>[2]>
  ) { }
}
```

Now things should work as desired, with the caveat that the compiler will not be able to infer the generic type argument from the `props` constructor argument.  That is, the type `PatchableProps<ConstructorParameters<C>[2]>` cannot be used to infer `C`.  So that type argument will need to be manually specified:

```
const x = new CompositionResource<typeof ApiObject>(
  // manually specified -------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  "abc",
  {}
)
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAxgCzgIwDYRgJwPZgDOAPACoB8UAvAFBRSlQQAewEAdgCaFQDeUAbQDWALiiFgOAJbsA5lAA+UdgFcAtmgg4AumLjsQUAL50oAfj6CA0hEMyoQ23gBmDXbAQp0WXARKkBGxBtShN6MUYleCRkGhoWMDwcYChEDDhCHgBhPDVEwilgKTx2ACUIQjwVHEQIYlMsplYObmUIAHcoAAo4HFkABj0DABooXtkARiGQUfGAJmnRgDoV8cJpgEpqSgBBMCkAeTQAKwhEYEpeOPocCDhOEow7Tg4i5yktMQlpOWooACIAJI5PJ4ApFErlSrVWr-ADc11SJW+KnOSS6pnoYBUmCkiCgt3uj0M7DgaggX0kMlkw0xUDA0gAbghoISHuwnvT8EQxNEvJhsNySDl2Ci0Th4DgyRA2DhheQBHMQqYtvwTCZ4sxEslUulMh4YnxTIhkZJUcB0arjDQNQkkik0hkeHtDiczikrvQTaKzeKMfQsTiMHiCXd2ZzKuTgMhqVNxFS5LSA-SgyG2cTxLkZTG5At4z8aXTsbj8emOYYGX4xABlLMHaNaXxEFWWdVxO06mSy5xwWpQWvk+vIRtC1txb0SKDMP7sDpQEH5QrFMoVKo1OqgSAuKAuo6nc7kf1QAD0x6gan0KjgGAjkEQUneEE4UAAtG-3y-KAA9H+-v--39TH+dBEH+JM+BMDY4iAA)